# Android Bluetooth Connectivity

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have posted a question but no one has answered yet. may be I have asked in a wrong way. so I am here to ask again.

here the link to my previous question
[IXXAT CANBlue II - Bluetooth java.io.IOException: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630407/ixxat-canblue-ii-bluetooth-java-io-ioexception-permission-denied)

Question:
why is it problem while connecting to **Bluetooth device** from android via Bluetooth.
Log Says **Permission Denied**. I am posting my Log here. my device works fine with PC Bluetooth terminal but when I tried to connect the device from my phone through app it pairs successfully but it cannot connect. and yes there is no problem in code as the code is Demo App provided by device makers and proper permissions are also added in manifest.. it was tested with android 3.2. and it worked well. but I Configured it on android studio 2.3.1 with following details.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ixxat.adk.demo"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 19
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Android Device with Android 4.0.2. and 4.4.2. but both have same problem.
Please help me out in this regard.

here are my log details.

```
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:266)
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at API.ADK.Driver$CANDevice.connectDevice(Driver.java:645)
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at API.ADK.API_ADK$Device.connectDevice(API_ADK.java:270)
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at ixxat.adk.demo.Demo_ADKActivity.onCreate(Demo_ADKActivity.java:91)
04-27 13:57:54.859 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-27 13:57:54.882 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-27 13:57:54.890 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-27 13:57:54.890 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-27 13:57:54.890 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-27 13:57:54.898 6434-6434/ixxat.adk.demo W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the manifest file as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ixxat.adk.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Demo_ADKActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show the manifest file please

Comment: @VladMatvienko sir I have edited my question and added manifest there. please have a look.

Comment: @VladMatvienko please help me sir. I am stuck with this problem from 5 days.

Comment: I don't see any problems so far. Which phones have you tried?

Comment: @VladMatvienko
LG G3 and a Tablet ARCHOS 10 their androiod versions I have mentioned in Question.

I am also not getting the point why it is giving me the error. I have searched the internet for 4 days but nothing helped. :(